# How to load ckeditor.js only in specific pages (CKEditor For WordPress)

Tags: performance, wordpress, ckeditor, pagespeed

I use CKEditor For WordPress and noticed that it slows down my site by loading ckeditor.js in pages where i don't need it at all.
How to prevent ckeditor.js from start in specific pages?